# Cant copy unique records from one database table to another?

Tags: mysql

Hi,

I am trying to copy unique records from a database table to another table of the same name but different database. The source database contains some records that are already present in the destination database, so those I dont need, only the other ones. Database destination is called "test" and the source database is "forums". The table name is store for both cases. I am using this query:

```
INSERT INTO test.store (cs_key, cs_value, cs_array, cs_updated,cs_rebuild)
SELECT DISTINCT cs_key, cs_value, cs_array, cs_updated,cs_rebuild
FROM forums.store
```

But I am getting many errors as I try to run this query. Why?

Thank you.

Comment: You always get one error at the time. Which one is it?

Comment: I get eleven at a time:     An expression was expected. (near "DISTINCT" at position 95)
    Unrecognized keyword. (near "DISTINCT" at position 95)
    Unexpected token. (near "cs_key" at position 104)
    Unexpected token. (near "," at position 110)
    Unexpected token. (near "cs_value" at position 112)
    Unexpected token. (near "," at position 120)
    Unexpected token. (near "cs_array" at position 122)
    Unexpected token. (near "," at position 130)
    Unexpected token. (near "cs_updated" at position 132)
    Unexpected token. (near "," at position 142)
    Unexpected token. (near "c

Comment: And since you insert into a test DB - just drop all records of that table before inserting

Comment: The first error is the relevant one. Are you sure you use MySQL? How you execute it?

Comment: My goal is to see which records need to be removed so I have to do it like this.

Comment: Exactly as I posted it. From phpmyadmin on the sql tab.

Comment: Is there any primary key in this table...on which basis you want to remove duplicate...

Comment: Try this query.. if it works ...    INSERT INTO test.store (cs_key, cs_value, cs_array, cs_updated,cs_rebuild)
(SELECT DISTINCT s.cs_key, s.cs_value, s.cs_array, s.cs_updated, s.cs_rebuild
FROM forums.store s)

Comment: cs_key is the primary. I just want to import the NOT duplicate records from one table to the other.

Comment: I still get the same error Pranav

Comment: It might be phpMyAdmin issue... can you please try running query from somewhere else, say from mysql command line ??

Comment: now im getting no error but not all the records were imported despite they were not duplicate.

Comment: was it a phpmyAdmin issue ??

Comment: Yes and no. On phpmyadmin I get the errors I posted above but from the command line I am getting this: Duplicate entry 'csite_nav_contents' for key 'PRIMARY'. Why is it even trying to import a duplicate entry? Thats why I am using DISTINCT for in the first place, isnt?